# How to delete rows if any of the columns is blank

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a worksheet that contains a lot of data and a lot of columns so that I can't do it manually.

I've searched for some answer here, but only found method for deleting row if particular column is blank, but I want the criterion to be any of the columns is blank.

Anybody can show me how to do it in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For i = 10 To 2 Step -1
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Sheet1.Range("A" & i & ":H" & i))) >= 1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that this assumes you're using Sheet1 and are checking only the values in the cells A through H.  Also, I used a hard-coded loop for demonstration purposes.  In your application, you should find the last row in code and use that rather than assuming you want to go from 10 to 2.

Additionally, when deleting rows you should go from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA is very simple if prepared to add a helper column with a formula such as:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A1:F1)
```

copied down to suit, where `F` above represents the last column (normally furthest to the right) that contains any data. Filter the helper column to select the column number (for F is `6`) and delete selection.